# Get SharePoint data in Cross Domain using REST-API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

We have (02) SharePoint farm in different domain and they are connected.

We need to access data from **Farm-A** SharePoint List in **Farm-B** using **Rest-API**

usually we calling REST API by just URL as below when in same domain. *But when domain is different what can we do?*

```
https://mysharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Events')/items 
?$top=1 
&$select=Title,Description,Date 
&$filter=ID eq 12
```

Answer (score 0):

For cross domain call, You can use **SP.AppContextSite**

Example:

```
appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, spHostUrl);

Nweb = appContextSite.get_web();
ctx.load(Nweb);
```

REST:

Now your rest url will be like below,

```
var url = appwebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbyTitle('Events')/items?$top=1&$select=Title,Description,Date&$filter=ID eq 12&@target='" + hostwebUrl + "'";
```

For refer in details, you follow [this link](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/cross-domain-and-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-rest/)
and [this link](http://weshackett.com/2014/02/sp-requestexecutor-cross-domain-calls-using-rest-gotcha/)

*If you find this answer as useful, upvote it.*

Comment: How should I pass the credentials?

Comment: Not required, same user must have access of another domain's site.

Comment: how domain1\user1 added in another domain? I mean how SharePoint find user1 in domain2?

Comment: User 1 is common for site, right? only domians are different?

Comment: But domain is not same doamin1\user1 and doamin2\user1.